# Animating transition in NavigationStack on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I made a simple macOS application with `NavigationStack` and few views presented using `NavigationLink(value:label:)`. It works really nice, except there is no animation at all. Is it possible to add animations to `NavigationStack` in this way? I can't use `withAnimation {}`, because it's not how `NavigationLink` works.

Comment: Just curious why would you need animation, it is standard functionality and users would like to see to see the view immediately? Instead you could animate the contents of the detail view

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution with NavigationStack but

Perhaps the solution to this problem will be the use of a **Mac Catalyst**.

For example, the following forces a stack-based navigation style, overriding the default double-column style on **Mac Catalyst**:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Hello Bananas", destination: Text(""))
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4BFz.gif)

I would be grateful if there is another solution